# Linux software that shows weekly Internet usage, broken down by domain

Tags: linux, networking, network-monitor

I want to see how the Internet usage from my Ubuntu 2013.10 machine is divided between hosts. Example:

```
43% Netflix
21% Jamendo
12% Wikicommons
8% Flickr
5% Mail.ru
3% Mysface
[...]
```

Requirements:

- Measure all traffic going through `wlan0`, both download/upload
- Show percentages (or data size) by domain
- Group subdomains (both `www.ibm.com` and `ftp.ibm.com` go into a single figure `ibm.com`)
- Don't show traffic *from* my computer *to* my computer
- Open Source

Strongly wanted:

- Intelligent grouping, for instance `1e100.net` is Google, `fbcdn.net` is Facebook
- Display as a chart (ideally a pie chart for the whole month).
- Don't include traffic between the OS and my local *VirtualBox* virtual machines.

Seen below, [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) is quite close, but unfortunately it shows local traffic, (`192.168.0.66` is the same machine, `ff02::fb` is localhost in IPv6, etc), and the host names are not useful, (`nrt*` is actually `nrt*.1e100.net`, which is Google).

[image: ntop example bar chart]

Comment: Major flaw in this... HTTPS. HTTPS will hide the actual domain making things far more complicated in your case.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev: It is not a problem. HTTPS does not hide IP addresses. Thus a simple reverse DNS lookup reveals the domain of any HTTPS request, even if the inside of the packets can not be seen.

Comment: What about when multiple services are under the same IP?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev: If several services run at the same IP, I am OK with them being represented as a single service.